# How to return a Date (not a TimeWithZone) from a Oracle date column in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, datetime, activerecord

Environment: Rails 2.2.2, Oracle 10g

Most of the columns declared "date" in my ActiveRecord models are exactly that: dates: they don't care about time at all.

So with a model declared thus:#

```
class MyDateOnlyModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :my_date_only_model do |t|
      t.date :effective_date
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

writing a test like this:

```
test_date = Date.new(2008,12,05)
MyDateOnlyModel.create!(:effective_date => test_date)
assert_equal test_date, MyDateOnlyModel.find(:first).effective_date
```

should pass, shouldn't it? (Assuming I didn't mess anything up transcribing the above, of course)

But it doesn't - not quite. I get this:

```
<Fri, 05 Dec 2008> expected but was
<Fri, 05 Dec 2008 00:00:00 UTC +00:00>.
```

So I put a date into the database and got ... well what *did* I get?

```
puts MyDateOnlyModel.find(:first).eff_date.class
```

tells me I actually got a `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. Which wasn't what I wanted at all.

Is there a simple way to tell ActiveRecord that some (not all) columns are `Date`s and only `Date`s?

UPDATE: more complaining...

Yes, I could use to_date:

```
assert_equal test_date, MyDateOnlyModel.find(:first).effective_date.to_date
```

works fine. But that's what I'm trying to avoid. I asked AR to make me a date, I want a date back.

And I could add a method to my class, effective_date_as_date - that works too. But surely it's not impossible to just get a date, dagnabbit.

**PRE-ACCEPTANCE UPDATE**

Eventually I realised why this was a particular problem with Oracle: there is no distinction between DATE and DATETIME, so ActiveRecord can't figure out unaided whether a time of zero means midnight (possibly with time zone corrections) or just the date. Bah. Stupid Oracle. So I'm going to have either to go down the plugin route, change my database (tempting, so very tempting) or continue with the to_date/to_time mess I have at present.

Comment: This isn't really an answer (and so I'm just making it a comment!), but I'd note that the DataMapper ORM supports this case by requiring that all properties be declared (with types) in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried casting your attribute to a Date type?

The API describes to_date as follows:

> Converts self to a Ruby Date object;
>   time portion is discarded

```
test_date = Date.new(2008,12,05)
MyDateOnlyModel.create!(:effective_date => test_date)
assert_equal test_date, MyDateOnlyModel.find(:first).effective_date.to_date
```

**Update**:

[Enhanced Oracle Adapter](http://blog.rayapps.com/2008/05/13/activerecord-oracle-enhanced-adapter/)

It looks like this adapter might have a fix for your problem...

> Set the option below and as a result
>   columns with DATE in their name will
>   be emulated as Date (and not as Time
>   which is default for DATE columns in
>   database)

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedAdapter.emulate_dates_by_column_name = true
```

Comment: Yes. And yuck. Really, really yuck.

I'm specifically trying to avoid having to write to_date all over my code. DRY and all that... I could override the accessor in my models where necessary, but yuck again.

Comment: What database are you using?  There could be the possibility that the column type that a Date object gets mapped to is not what you think in your database.  Very doubtful, but possible.

Comment: Oracle: it's a DATE column, which can take a time value as well. I seem to suffer unduly with dates and times whatever the DB, which makes me think I'm missing something...  :)

Comment: Have you tried the Enhanced Oracle Adapter for ActiveRecord?  I've used Rails with Oracle in the past and it's an interesting mix.  It looks like though it may fix your problem!  See my answer for link.

Comment: Months later: I'm using Oracle enhanced and having a better time of it.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered a bug: you can't compare TimWithZone with a Date.  Comparison fails, ruby tells me.

Comment: You're absolutely right: that's why there's all this horrid to_date/to_time stuff going on. I just can't believe I'm the only one who's feeling the pain, nor does it seem likely that it hasn't been addressed. But perhaps I'm wrong.